# Facebook, OAuth 2.0, and JavaScript SDK issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've coded up a plugin for OAuth 2.0 for Grails. Everything works fine except for one issue.

If the person has been logged into Facebook already for a while. The act of the Facebook popup...popping up and instantly going away doesn't do something that I must need.

If the person flushes their cache and tries to login it forces them to login and then works.
What is it the popup dialog does not do if you are already logged in? It still would set the fbsr_ cookie right?

*issue update:*
I can reproduce the issue with my plugin. Need some suggestion on where to go from here:
 - Clear all cookies / cache etc...
- Log in (I get the full Facebook popup) and I'm required to login. It works.
- Open new tab, go to facebook.com, and log out
- Go back to my home page, get fb popup, again I'm required to login. It fails.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got it wrong, but I try to guess anyway: Are you using the  *FB.login()* method.
If you do I'd suggest you to use also the method *FB.getLoginStatus* as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

Best regards

Luca